# Evaluating the three-dimensional integral $\int d^{3}\vec{k} \frac{\exp(i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R})}{k^{2}(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to integrate the following,
$$\int d^{3}\vec{k} \frac{\exp(i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R})}{k^{2}(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}},$$
where $\vec{R}$ is a constant real vector. The integration is over the full space $0<k<\infty$, $0<\theta<\pi$, $0<\phi<2\pi$.

I have taken $\vec{R}$ along the direction of $z$ axis to simplify the problem. I proceeded as follows:
$$\int k^{2}dk \sin\theta d\theta d\phi\frac{\exp(ikR\cos\theta)}{k^{2}(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}}$$
$d\phi$ integral gives $2\pi$,
$$\int dk\int d(-\cos\theta)\frac{\exp(ikR\cos\theta)}{(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} $$
$$-\int_{0}^{\infty} dk\int_{0}^{\pi} d(\cos\theta)\frac{\exp(ikR\cos\theta)}{(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} $$
$$-\int_{0}^{\infty} dk\int_{1}^{-1} d(\cos\theta)\frac{\exp(ikR\cos\theta)}{(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} $$ integrating $\theta$ integral completely we get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dk \frac{\exp(ikR)-\exp(-ikR)}{ikR(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} $$ Rearranging further,$$\frac{1}{iR}\int_{0}^{\infty} dk \frac{\exp(ikR)-\exp(-ikR)}{k(k^{2}+a^{2})^{2}} $$  How do proceed further from here. Can someone help me solving this problem completely to get the final answer?

Comment: Use $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+a^2)^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{4a^4}\left(2-\frac{2+|a|}{e^{|a|}}\right)$ .

Comment: @user90369 How do we get this final result can you please explain a bit ? thank you so much for giving this final result

Comment: It was only a comment, I’ve not the time to write a whole answer, sorry. Use WolframAlpha if necessary. The last step with $\,\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+y^2)^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{4y^4}\left(2-\frac{2+|y|}{e^{|y|}}\right)\,$ is to substitute $x$ by $kR$ and $y$ by $aR$ ; $R$ is a positive real number here. Then you get the final result. And you know of course: $e^{ikR}-e^{-ikR}=i2\sin(kR)$

Comment: Well done up to the last but one line! Your last integral gives $\frac{\pi  \left(2-e^{-a R} (a R+2)\right)}{2 a^4 R}$ if $R\gt0$ and $a\gt0$ which we can assume without loss on generality.